# Length of arrow in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Looking at the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[scale=10]
    F_n \otimes M \arrow{r}[name=U]{\phi_n \otimes M} & F_{n-1}\otimes M  \\
    F_n\otimes L \arrow[hookrightarrow]{u}{\tilde{\iota}_n} \arrow[swap]{r}[name=D]{\phi_n \otimes L} & F_{n-1}\otimes L \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{u}{\tilde{\iota}_{n-1}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

we get the commutative diagramm

[image]

How is it possible lengthen the arrows?

Comment: `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large]`. Instead of `large`, you may put any measure you like. E.g. `10ex`

Comment: That works perfectly fine! Tanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can lengthen the arrows with the parameters `row sep` and `column sep` which define the distance between two nodes/cells in your diagram.

Here a quote from the excellent documentation:

> [image]

In your case, `large` or `huge` would do the trick if you want to stick to predefined values (nice for consistency):
[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
    \texttt{row sep=large, column sep=large}\\
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep = large]
        F_n \otimes M \arrow{r}[name=U]{\phi_n \otimes M} & F_{n-1}\otimes M  \\
        F_n\otimes L \arrow[hookrightarrow]{u}{\tilde{\iota}_n} \arrow[swap]{r}[name=D]{\phi_n \otimes L} & F_{n-1}\otimes L \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{u}{\tilde{\iota}_{n-1}}
    \end{tikzcd}\\
    \texttt{row sep=huge, column sep=huge}\\
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep = huge]
        F_n \otimes M \arrow{r}[name=U]{\phi_n \otimes M} & F_{n-1}\otimes M  \\
        F_n\otimes L \arrow[hookrightarrow]{u}{\tilde{\iota}_n} \arrow[swap]{r}[name=D]{\phi_n \otimes L} & F_{n-1}\otimes L \arrow[hookrightarrow,swap]{u}{\tilde{\iota}_{n-1}}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

You can go further by setting any other measure like `row sep=5cm`. It is considered good practise to stick to relative lengths. This would be `em` for horizontal (e.g. `column sep=10em`) and `ex` for vertical (e.g. `row sep=10ex`) values.

If you prefer to set the distance between the node centres (not between their edges), you might choose something like `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={40,between origins}, column sep={40,between origins}]`. This example uses the Ti*k*Z unit (1cm is default, I believe).

---

In case you just want to change the length between two columns resp. rows, you can do this like the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar &[20em] B \rar & C \\
    D \rar & E \rar & F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \dar & B \dar \\[20ex]
    C \dar & D \dar \\
    E & F
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

---

If you want to change the length of single arrows, you have to shorten them. You can do this in negative direction (elongation) as well.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
     A \rar[shorten <= 2em]\dar[shorten <= 2ex] & B \rar[shorten >= 2em]\dar[shorten >= 2ex] & C \rar[shorten <= 1em, shorten >= 1em]\dar[shorten <= 1ex, shorten >= 1ex] & D\dar[shorten <= -.7ex, shorten >= -.7ex] \\
     E \rar[shorten <= -.5em] & F \rar[shorten >= -.4em] & G \rar[shorten <= -.5em, shorten >= -.5em] & H 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]