# Shorten some horizontals with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

The following `tikz-cd` code produces the diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzcd}
  A & B \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & C \arrow[d] \\
  D& E \arrow[r] &F
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

How, if at all, is it possible to move the A and D closer to B and E, respectively (while still keeping them horizontally and vertically aligned, of course)?

After greatly revising my question to the one above, I discovered at  [Length of arrow in tikz-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254613/length-of-arrow-in-tikz-cd) the use of optional parameter to `&` to change the spacing of columns. And egreg's answer shows just that.

Comment: Sorry for changing my question so much so quickly. The preferred answers do answer my original question; egret's also answers my emended question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think to the diagram as a matrix: we have two rows and three columns; so in each row we need two `&` characters. In each cell add the arrows starting from it, with their target.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & C \arrow[d] \\
D \arrow[r] & E \arrow[r] & F
\end{tikzcd}
```

If the diagram is more complicated, it's not really different. For instance, suppose we have A on the top row with arrows pointing to B, C and D on the bottom row, with A above B; we also want an arrow from B to C and one from C to D.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[rd,"g"] \arrow[rrd,"h"] \\
B \arrow[r,"\beta"] & C \arrow[r,"\gamma"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Oh, wait! The second diagram is very bad!

We get a better one by spacing more the columns and by changing the positions of the labels:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em]
A \arrow[d,swap,"f"] \arrow[rd,swap,"g"] \arrow[rrd,"h"] \\
B \arrow[r,swap,"\beta"] & C \arrow[r,swap,"\gamma"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Better yet: make it more symmetric:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em]
& A \arrow[dl,swap,"f"] \arrow[d,swap,"g"] \arrow[rd,"h"] \\
B \arrow[r,swap,"\beta"] & C \arrow[r,swap,"\gamma"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

For shortening the distance between two columns, use the optional parameter to `&`:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A &[-2em] B \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & C \arrow[d] \\
D & E \arrow[r] & F
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish the same thing as in the final image (with no arrows from/to A or D and closer horizontal spacing to their right) by means of phantom arrows? That's what I tried first, to no avail.

Comment: @murray What phantom arrows? Besides, use a method that works. ;-)

Comment: OK. And is it possible to use something like `\text{Top}` in place of A for a node? (I tried but get "undefined control sequence error.)

Comment: It certainly would have helped if the `tikz-cd` documentation had said something like the 1st paragraph of your answer! (Perhaps it should have been obvious, but it wasn't to me.)

Comment: @murray `\text` requires `amsmath`. About why the analogy with matrices is not spelled out, I can only assume that the author thought everybody was aware of it.

Comment: Yep, I was forgetting to load `amsmath`. I do that in all my source files but forgot it in the `standalone` documentclass source file I used for this. All problems (for now!) solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can make such a diagram either with tikz-cd or with `pstricks`, more specifically with the the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pst-node,  multido, auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
A\dar \rar [dashed] & B\dar\rar [dashed] & C\dar\\%
D \rar [dashed] & E \rar [dashed] & F
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[ \def\pscolhookii{\hskip-.4cm}
  \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1.2cm,  rowsep=0.8cm]
%% nodes
A & B & C\\
D & E & F
%%arrows
 \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, nodesep=3pt,  linewidth=0.6pt}
 \ncline{1,1}{2,1} \ncline{1,2}{2,2} \ncline{1,3}{2,3}
 \psset{ linestyle=dashed,  dash=3pt 2pt}
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2} \ncline{1,2}{1,3}
 \ncline{2,1}{2,2} \ncline{2,2}{2,3}
 \psset{ linestyle =dash}
\end{psmatrix}%
 \] %

\end{document}
```

**Added:** For your new requirement, I know how to do that with `pstricks`, and I've updated my code accordingly.

[image]