# reducing size of a diagram in tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, size

Following is the minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{tikzcd}
    & & (\mc{G}_1\times_M \mc{H}_1)/\mc{G}_1 \arrow[ldd] \arrow[rdd] & & \\
    & & \mc{G}_1 \arrow[dd,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]\arrow[dd,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"'] & & \mc{H}_1 \arrow[dd,xshift=0.75ex,"t"]\arrow[dd,xshift=-0.75ex,"s"'] \\
    & \mc{G}_1 \arrow[ld, "t_{\mc{G}}"'] \arrow[rd, "s_{\mc{G}}"] & & \mc{H}_1 \arrow[ld, "t_{\mc{H}}"'] \arrow[rd] & \\
    M & & M & & M 
    \end{tikzcd}.\end{equation}

    \begin{equation}    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
    \underline{M} \arrow[dd,"L"'] \arrow[rr, "G"] & & \underline{N} \arrow[dd, "q"] \\
    & & \\
    \mc{D} \arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=20pt, shorten <=20pt, uurr] \arrow[rr, "F"] & & \mc{C}
    \end{tikzcd}. \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Question is the following:

> Is the size of a diagram in tikzcd fixed or can one increase or decrease the size of the diagram?

I have followed suggestion in the below answer. It worked for the first diagram (in the edited version) but, second diagram has distorted. I am adding the picture of it.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325297/how-to-scale-a-tikzcd-diagram) help you?

Comment: @Steradiant thanks. it helped in some sense..

Comment: Inverse question: [Length of arrow in tikz-cd - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254613/length-of-arrow-in-tikz-cd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tikz-cd` has several options to change the size, such as `sep=tiny`, `small`, `large` or `huge`, or the `cramped` option. They are described on p. 7 of the manual. However, as `tikz-cd` is "secretly" a Ti*k*Z `matrix`, you can also use the `tikz` keys `column sep` or `row sep`, and access all the other styles of sections 20 and 60 of `pgfmanual` v3.1.5. The discussion of matrices in the pgfmanual is likely be extended in the future.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
& & (\mathcal{G}_1\times_M \mathcal{H}_1)/\mathcal{G}_1 \arrow[ldd] \arrow[rdd] & & \\
& & \mathcal{G}_1 \arrow[dd,shift left=0.75ex,"t"]\arrow[dd,shift left=-0.75ex,"s"'] & &
\mathcal{H}_1 \arrow[dd,shift left=0.75ex,"t"]\arrow[dd,shift left=-0.75ex,"s"'] \\
& \mathcal{G}_1 \arrow[ld, "t_{\mathcal{G}}"'] \arrow[rd, "s_{\mathcal{G}}"] & & \mathcal{H}_1 \arrow[ld, "t_{\mathcal{H}}"'] \arrow[rd] & \\
M & & M & & M 
\end{tikzcd}\;.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1ex,row sep=1ex]
& & (\mathcal{G}_1\times_M \mathcal{H}_1)/\mathcal{G}_1 \arrow[ldd] \arrow[rdd] & & \\
& & \mathcal{G}_1 \arrow[dd,shift left=0.75ex,"t"]\arrow[dd,shift left=-0.75ex,"s"'] & &
\mathcal{H}_1 \arrow[dd,shift left=0.75ex,"t"]\arrow[dd,shift left=-0.75ex,"s"'] \\
& \mathcal{G}_1 \arrow[ld, "t_{\mathcal{G}}"'] \arrow[rd, "s_{\mathcal{G}}"] & & \mathcal{H}_1 \arrow[ld, "t_{\mathcal{H}}"'] \arrow[rd] & \\
M & & M & & M 
\end{tikzcd}\;.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me also mention that the example you are giving is working, but not really minimal. I also replace the `xshift` by `shift left`.

Comment: oh no :D  It does not look good.. :(

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Well, that's your opinion. I have no idea what your aesthetics preferences are, but this post does answer the question `Is the size of a diagram in tikzcd fixed or can one increase or decrease the size of the diagram?`, though.

Comment: Yes Yes.. It does answer my question :)

Comment: Not minimal in what sense?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It has a huge preamble, most of which is not relevant for the question/diagram. To produce the diagram the small preamble of the answer is sufficient. (While there are different opinions, I do not recommend using macros like `\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}` since, if you ever collaborate with others and share the code, and each collaborator has their own macros, the confusion is tremendous. But this is just an opinion.) "Minimal" means the minimal amount of packages and macros relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I am planning to collaborate with some one.. I will keep your suggestion in mind...

Comment: Hi.. I have used your suggestion. It was useful.. But It created a problem in other part. I have added it to the question. please see if you can help.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik When I compile your code, I do not get a distorted diagram. The only problem is `shorten >=20pt, shorten <=20pt,` in `\arrow[Rightarrow, shorten >=20pt, shorten <=20pt, uurr] `. If I remove these keys, i.e. use `\arrow[Rightarrow,  uurr]` instead, the diagram looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes,, that 20pt was creating a problem..  If I remove it looks fine. Thank you.